# Stored Procedure That Insert Multi Row in a Table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I would like to insert more than one line into a table in a stored procedure,
It must be taken into concord that my values are recovered in a temporary array as follows:

```
mysql> select * from temp_tblist;

mysql> select * from temp_tblist ;

+------------------------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| id                           | NOm           | Mois         | Remise    |
+------------------------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| 1                            |Côte d'Ivoire  |Janvier 2019  | 2         |
| 2                            | Sénégal       | Janvier 2019 | 1         |
+------------------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.30 sec)
```

The result of my procedure should be as follows:

```
mysql>  call GET_ECERBER_STAT_BY_LIST('2018-01-01','2019-12-29','NBReceived','CIV,SN',null);


+------------------------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| Titre                        | Valeur1       | Valeur2      | Valeur3   |
+------------------------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| Côte d'Ivoire                |10             |15            | 21        |
| Sénégal                      |2              |5             | 11        |
+------------------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.30 sec)
```

Currently, I can insert in the table only one value as follows:

```
mysql>  call GET_ECERBER_STAT_BY_LIST('2018-01-01','2019-12-29','NBReceived','CIV',null); 
+------------------------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| Titre                        | Valeur1       | Valeur2      | Valeur3   |
+------------------------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| Côte d'Ivoire                |10             |15            | 21        |
+------------------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
1 rows in set (0.30 sec)
```

Adding create syntax for the sp

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GET_ECERBER_STAT_BY_LIST`(datedebut DATETIME, datefin DATETIME,information VARCHAR(4000),IN  str_pays VARCHAR(4000),str_banque VARCHAR(4000))
BEGIN
     if information = 'NBReceived' then
      DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_tblist; 
      truncate table stat_by_list; 
      SET @row_number = 0;
      SET lc_time_names = 'fr_FR';        
      CREATE   TABLE temp_tblist(
    id INT(100) NOT NULL, Pays varchar(255) NOT NULL, Mois varchar(255) NOT NULL,Remise INT(100) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)) 
    ENGINE=MEMORY AS (select (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) as id,c.name_ as Pays,CONCAT(UCASE(MID(DATE_FORMAT(rr.date_,"%M %Y"),1,1)),LCASE(MID(DATE_FORMAT(rr.date_,"%M %Y"),2))) as Mois,count(*) as Remise from REGULATORYR rr INNER JOIN country c ON rr.COUNTRYPK_=c.pk_
    where rr.date_ in (select distinct rr.date_ as dater 
    from REGULATORYR rr, country c
    where rr.date_>=datedebut and rr.date_<= datefin
    and c.pk_=rr.countrypk_
    group by substring(rr.date_,1,7))
    and c.pk_=rr.countrypk_  and c.CODE_ = str_pays
    group by COUNTRYPK_, substring(rr.date_,1,7)
    order by c.name_);                     
    set @name_pays  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=1);
    set @val1  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=1);set @val2 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=2);set @val3  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=3);set @val4  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=4);
    set @val5  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=5);set @val6  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=6);set @val7  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=7);set @val8  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=8);
    set @val9  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=9);set @val10 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=10);set @val11 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=11);set @val12 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=12);
    set @val13 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=13);set @val14 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=14);set @val15 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=15);set @val16 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=16);
    set @val17 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=17);set @val18 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=18);set @val19 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=19);set @val20 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=20);
    set @val21 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=21);set @val22 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=22);set @val23 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=23);set @val24 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=24);
    set @val25 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=25);set @val26  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=26);set @val27  =(SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=27);set @val28  =(SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=28);
    set @val29  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=29);set @val30  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=30);set @val31  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=31);set @val32  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=32);
    set @val33  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=33);set @val34  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=34);set @val35 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=35);set @val36 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=36);
    set @val37 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=37);set @val38 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=38);set @val39 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=39);set @val40 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=40);
    set @val41 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=41);set @val42 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=42);set @val43 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=43);set @val44 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=44);
    set @val45 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=45);set @val46 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=46);set @val47 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=47);set @val48 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=48);
    set @val49 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=49);set @val50 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=50);set @val51  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=51);
    insert into stat_by_list(TITRE_,VALEUR1_,VALEUR2_,VALEUR3_,VALEUR4_,VALEUR5_,VALEUR6_,VALEUR7_,VALEUR8_,VALEUR9_,VALEUR10_,VALEUR11_,VALEUR12_,VALEUR13_,VALEUR14_,VALEUR15_,VALEUR16_,VALEUR17_,VALEUR18_,VALEUR19_,VALEUR20_,VALEUR21_,VALEUR22_,VALEUR23_,VALEUR24_,VALEUR25_,VALEUR26_,VALEUR27_,VALEUR28_,VALEUR29_,VALEUR30_,VALEUR31_,VALEUR32_,VALEUR33_,VALEUR34_,VALEUR35_,VALEUR36_,VALEUR37_,VALEUR38_,VALEUR39_,VALEUR40_,VALEUR41_,VALEUR42_,VALEUR43_,VALEUR44_,VALEUR45_,VALEUR46_,VALEUR47_,VALEUR48_,VALEUR49_,
        VALEUR50_) 
        values (@name_pays,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,
        @val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,
        @val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,
        @val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,
        @val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50
    );      
        select * from stat_by_list;
    end if;
    End
```

and create table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stat_by_list(TITRE_ VARCHAR(255),VALEUR1_ INT(11),
    VALEUR2_ INT(11),VALEUR3_ INT(11),VALEUR4_ INT(11),VALEUR5_ INT(11),
VALEUR6_ INT(11),VALEUR7_ INT(11),VALEUR8_ INT(11),VALEUR9_ INT(11),
VALEUR10_ INT(11),VALEUR11_ INT(11),VALEUR12_ INT(11),
VALEUR13_ ......,VALEUR50_ );
```

Comment: need more info, share the create procedure

Comment: @James :fere is my code

Comment: share create statement for stat_by_list table

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stat_by_list(TITRE_ VARCHAR(255),VALEUR1_ INT(11), VALEUR2_ INT(11),VALEUR3_ INT(11),VALEUR4_ INT(11),VALEUR5_ INT(11),VALEUR6_ INT(11),VALEUR7_ INT(11),VALEUR8_ INT(11),VALEUR9_ INT(11),VALEUR10_ INT(11),VALEUR11_ INT(11),VALEUR12_ INT(11),VALEUR13_ ......,VALEUR50_ );

Comment: The procedure must return the Discount=='Remise' (Value1, Value2 ... Value 50) for a period (date debut, date fin)  of all countries (str_country)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GET_ECERBER_STAT_BY_LIST`(datedebut DATETIME, datefin DATETIME,information VARCHAR(4000),IN  str_pays VARCHAR(4000),str_banque VARCHAR(4000))
BEGIN
     if information = 'NBReceived' then
      DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_tblist; 
      truncate table stat_by_list; 
      SET @row_number = 0;
      SET lc_time_names = 'fr_FR';        
      CREATE   TABLE temp_tblist(
    id INT(100) NOT NULL, Pays varchar(255) NOT NULL, Mois varchar(255) NOT NULL,Remise INT(100) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)) 
    ENGINE=MEMORY AS (select (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) as id,c.name_ as Pays,CONCAT(UCASE(MID(DATE_FORMAT(rr.date_,"%M %Y"),1,1)),LCASE(MID(DATE_FORMAT(rr.date_,"%M %Y"),2))) as Mois,count(*) as Remise from REGULATORYR rr INNER JOIN country c ON rr.COUNTRYPK_=c.pk_
    where rr.date_ in (select distinct rr.date_ as dater 
    from REGULATORYR rr, country c
    where rr.date_>=datedebut and rr.date_<= datefin
    and c.pk_=rr.countrypk_
    group by substring(rr.date_,1,7))
    and c.pk_=rr.countrypk_  and c.CODE_ = str_pays
    group by COUNTRYPK_, substring(rr.date_,1,7)
    order by c.name_);                     
    set @name_pays  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=1);
    set @val1  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=1);set @val2 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=2);set @val3  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=3);set @val4  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=4);
    set @val5  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=5);set @val6  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=6);set @val7  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=7);set @val8  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=8);
    set @val9  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=9);set @val10 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=10);set @val11 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=11);set @val12 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=12);
    set @val13 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=13);set @val14 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=14);set @val15 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=15);set @val16 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=16);
    set @val17 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=17);set @val18 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=18);set @val19 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=19);set @val20 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=20);
    set @val21 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=21);set @val22 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=22);set @val23 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=23);set @val24 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=24);
    set @val25 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=25);set @val26  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=26);set @val27  =(SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=27);set @val28  =(SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=28);
    set @val29  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=29);set @val30  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=30);set @val31  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=31);set @val32  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=32);
    set @val33  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=33);set @val34  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=34);set @val35 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=35);set @val36 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=36);
    set @val37 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=37);set @val38 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=38);set @val39 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=39);set @val40 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=40);
    set @val41 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=41);set @val42 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=42);set @val43 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=43);set @val44 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=44);
    set @val45 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=45);set @val46 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=46);set @val47 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=47);set @val48 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=48);
    set @val49 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=49);set @val50 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=50);set @val51  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=51);
    insert into stat_by_list(TITRE_,VALEUR1_,VALEUR2_,VALEUR3_,VALEUR4_,VALEUR5_,VALEUR6_,VALEUR7_,VALEUR8_,VALEUR9_,VALEUR10_,VALEUR11_,VALEUR12_,VALEUR13_,VALEUR14_,VALEUR15_,VALEUR16_,VALEUR17_,VALEUR18_,VALEUR19_,VALEUR20_,VALEUR21_,VALEUR22_,VALEUR23_,VALEUR24_,VALEUR25_,VALEUR26_,VALEUR27_,VALEUR28_,VALEUR29_,VALEUR30_,VALEUR31_,VALEUR32_,VALEUR33_,VALEUR34_,VALEUR35_,VALEUR36_,VALEUR37_,VALEUR38_,VALEUR39_,VALEUR40_,VALEUR41_,VALEUR42_,VALEUR43_,VALEUR44_,VALEUR45_,VALEUR46_,VALEUR47_,VALEUR48_,VALEUR49_,
        VALEUR50_) 
        values (@name_pays,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,
        @val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,
        @val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,
        @val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,
        @val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50
    );      
        select * from stat_by_list;
    end if;
    End
```

Comment: Unless this is an answer this should have been added to the question. Please EDIT the question adding this to it and then delete the answer. (If people see you have answered your own question they will in all likelihood move on)

Comment: I added the code following a request from @James because I can not add it in a comment

Comment: he said to edit your question in there add the create syntax for the procedure.

Comment: ahh ok, i did it: GET_ECERBER_STAT_BY_LIST

Comment: have you figured out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here goes, found that you are inserting only for the `@name_pays` of id=1, that is why you get only one row as a result set. Try the below procedure,

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GET_ECERBER_STAT_BY_LIST`(datedebut DATETIME, datefin DATETIME,information VARCHAR(4000),IN  str_pays VARCHAR(4000),str_banque VARCHAR(4000))
BEGIN
     if information = 'NBReceived' then
      DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_tblist; 
      truncate table stat_by_list; 
      SET @row_number = 0;
      SET lc_time_names = 'fr_FR';        
      CREATE   TABLE temp_tblist(
    id INT(100) NOT NULL, Pays varchar(255) NOT NULL, Mois varchar(255) NOT NULL,Remise INT(100) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)) 
    ENGINE=MEMORY AS (select (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) as id,c.name_ as Pays,CONCAT(UCASE(MID(DATE_FORMAT(rr.date_,"%M %Y"),1,1)),LCASE(MID(DATE_FORMAT(rr.date_,"%M %Y"),2))) as Mois,count(*) as Remise from REGULATORYR rr INNER JOIN country c ON rr.COUNTRYPK_=c.pk_
    where rr.date_ in (select distinct rr.date_ as dater 
    from REGULATORYR rr, country c
    where rr.date_>=datedebut and rr.date_<= datefin
    and c.pk_=rr.countrypk_
    group by substring(rr.date_,1,7))
    and c.pk_=rr.countrypk_  and c.CODE_ = str_pays
    group by COUNTRYPK_, substring(rr.date_,1,7)
    order by c.name_);                     
set @name_pays1  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=1);set @name_pays2  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=2);set @name_pays3  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=3);set @name_pays4  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=4);set @name_pays5  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=5);set @name_pays6  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=6);set @name_pays7  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=7);set @name_pays8  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=8);set @name_pays9  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=9);set @name_pays10  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=10);set @name_pays11  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=11);set @name_pays12  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=12);set @name_pays13  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=13);set @name_pays14  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=14);set @name_pays15  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=15);set @name_pays16  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=16);set @name_pays17  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=17);set @name_pays18  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=18);set @name_pays19  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=19);set @name_pays20  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=20);set @name_pays21  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=21);set @name_pays22  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=22);set @name_pays23  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=23);set @name_pays24  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=24);set @name_pays25  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=25);set @name_pays26  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=26);set @name_pays27  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=27);set @name_pays28  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=28);set @name_pays29  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=29);set @name_pays30  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=30);set @name_pays31  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=31);set @name_pays32  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=32);set @name_pays33  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=33);set @name_pays34  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=34);set @name_pays35  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=35);set @name_pays36  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=36);set @name_pays37  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=37);set @name_pays38  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=38);set @name_pays39  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=39);set @name_pays40  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=40);set @name_pays41  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=41);set @name_pays42  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=42);set @name_pays43  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=43);set @name_pays44  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=44);set @name_pays45  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=45);set @name_pays46  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=46);set @name_pays47  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=47);set @name_pays48  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=48);set @name_pays49  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=49);set @name_pays50  = (SELECT Pays FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=50);  
    set @val1  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=1);set @val2 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=2);set @val3  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=3);set @val4  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=4);
    set @val5  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=5);set @val6  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=6);set @val7  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=7);set @val8  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=8);
    set @val9  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=9);set @val10 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=10);set @val11 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=11);set @val12 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=12);
    set @val13 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=13);set @val14 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=14);set @val15 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=15);set @val16 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=16);
    set @val17 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=17);set @val18 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=18);set @val19 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=19);set @val20 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=20);
    set @val21 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=21);set @val22 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=22);set @val23 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=23);set @val24 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=24);
    set @val25 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=25);set @val26  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=26);set @val27  =(SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=27);set @val28  =(SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=28);
    set @val29  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=29);set @val30  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=30);set @val31  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=31);set @val32  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=32);
    set @val33  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=33);set @val34  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=34);set @val35 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=35);set @val36 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=36);
    set @val37 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=37);set @val38 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=38);set @val39 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=39);set @val40 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=40);
    set @val41 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=41);set @val42 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=42);set @val43 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=43);set @val44 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=44);
    set @val45 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=45);set @val46 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=46);set @val47 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=47);set @val48 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=48);
    set @val49 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=49);set @val50 = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=50);set @val51  = (SELECT Remise FROM temp_tblist WHERE id=51);
    insert into stat_by_list(TITRE_,VALEUR1_,VALEUR2_,VALEUR3_,VALEUR4_,VALEUR5_,VALEUR6_,VALEUR7_,VALEUR8_,VALEUR9_,VALEUR10_,VALEUR11_,VALEUR12_,VALEUR13_,VALEUR14_,VALEUR15_,VALEUR16_,VALEUR17_,VALEUR18_,VALEUR19_,VALEUR20_,VALEUR21_,VALEUR22_,VALEUR23_,VALEUR24_,VALEUR25_,VALEUR26_,VALEUR27_,VALEUR28_,VALEUR29_,VALEUR30_,VALEUR31_,VALEUR32_,VALEUR33_,VALEUR34_,VALEUR35_,VALEUR36_,VALEUR37_,VALEUR38_,VALEUR39_,VALEUR40_,VALEUR41_,VALEUR42_,VALEUR43_,VALEUR44_,VALEUR45_,VALEUR46_,VALEUR47_,VALEUR48_,VALEUR49_,
        VALEUR50_) 
        values ((@name_pays1,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays2,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays3,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays4,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays5,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays6,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays7,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays8,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays9,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays10,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays11,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays12,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays13,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays14,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays15,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays16,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays17,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays18,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays19,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays20,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays21,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays22,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays23,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays24,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays25,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays26,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays27,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays28,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays29,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays30,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays31,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays32,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays33,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays34,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays35,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays36,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays37,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays38,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays39,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays40,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays41,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays42,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays43,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays44,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays45,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays46,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays47,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays48,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays49,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50),
(@name_pays50,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4, @val5,@val6,@val7,@val8,@val9,@val10,@val11,@val12,@val13,@val14,@val15,@val16,@val17,@val18,@val19,@val20,@val21,@val22,@val23,@val24,@val25,@val26,@val27,@val28,@val29,@val30,@val31,@val32,@val33,@val34,@val35,@val36,@val37,@val38,@val39,@val40,@val41,@val42,@val43,@val44,@val45,@val46,@val47,@val48,@val49,@val50));      
        select * from stat_by_list;
    end if;
    End
```

Comment: Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: check the column in the insert query whether 1 to 50 value is created or you have missed a column.

Comment: it's not dynamic like this:
The following query: select * from temp_tblist; return:

`id Country Month Discount
9 Ivory Coast April 2019 1
6 Ivory Coast January 2019 5
3 Ivory Coast April 2018 1
8 Ivory Coast March 2019 1
5 Ivory Coast July 2018 1
2 Ivory Coast May 2018 1
10 Ivory Coast May 2019 1
7 Ivory Coast February 2019 1
4 Ivory Coast June 2018 1
1 Ivory Coast March 2018 1
11 Senegal January 2019 1`